# How to fix an MIME type error with Chromedriver?

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium-chromedriver, jqmigrate

I have written a selenium script with python. It works fine when I run it with Visual Studio, however when I package the script into an .exe file, the chromedriver window appears with the following:
"JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.1".

The next line reads:
"Refused to apply style from '*URL I am accessing*.css ' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.", source: *URL I am accessing*."

I don't have the capability to change the way the .css is embedded in the webpage, any ideas how to overcome this as it is quite a big blocker at the moment?